# How to delete different string date with stored procedure in SQL and asp.net core

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am to delete from a table that dates are stored in string format. The hours, mins are not consistent.eg These dates are from different sources that I cant control

- 2020-10-16 12:00:00
- AM 2020-10-16 12:00:00 AM
- 2020-10-16 12:00:00 AM
- 2020-10-18 00:00:00.0000000
- 2020-8-31 00:00:00.0000000
- 2020-10-21 00:00:00.0000000
- 2020-9-30 00:00:00.0000000
- 2020-10-21 12:00:00.0000000
- 2020-09-30 00:00:00

It's Only the year, month, and date that I can determine from my code. I can only pass eg "2020-09-30" from the C# code to my stored procedure. I have to delete all the occurrences associated with that date and accountNo before inserting a new record.

How can I make this happen?

```
alter procedure [dbo].[DeleteFromStatement](
@AccountNo varchar(50),
@Date varchar(250)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[MonthlyInterest] WHERE AccountNo=@AccountNo AND Date=@Date 
END
```

Comment: Fix the logic!  Pass the value in as a `datetime` and make the caller convert to the correct type.

Comment: Use the LIKE operator for the dates, as in `LIKE '%2020-10-18%'`

Comment: Also, fire the developer who used varchar for datetime data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PATINDEX` function could be used.

If the date is passed in as VARCHAR(250) you could use the TRIM function.  If using an older version the LTRIM(RTRIM(...)) could be used.

```
alter procedure [dbo].[DeleteFromStatement](
  @AccountNo    varchar(50),
  @Date         varchar(250))
as
set nocount on;

delete mt
from  [dbo].[MonthlyInterest] mt
where AccountNo=@AccountNo
      and patindex('%'+ltrim(rtrim(@Date))+'%', mt.Date)>0;
go
```

If the date is passed in as a date you could use CAST(@dt as char(10))

```
alter procedure [dbo].[DeleteFromStatement](
  @AccountNo    varchar(50),
  @Date         date)
as
set nocount on;

delete mt
from  [dbo].[MonthlyInterest] mt
where AccountNo=@AccountNo
      and patindex('%'+cast(@Date as char(10))+'%', mt.Date)>0;
go
```

Comment: what of this '2020-8-31' record in the database. Will your solution delete such?

Comment: Updated.  The date could be whatever is passed as a parameter

Comment: ```multipart identifier " t.code" could not be found```

Comment: ```Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Procedure DeleteFromStatement, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 7]
'trim' is not a recognized built-in function name.```

Comment: Older version of SQL Server could use a combination of LTRIM(RTRIM()).  It's updated